# How to align html elements in a single line?

Tags: html, css

I have a text,choose button and image.Need to align it in ***a single line***.               But it is coming one after the other.
My html code is :

```
 <script>
 File :<input type="file" name="files"/>
       <img src="abc.jpg"/>
 </script>
```

Comment: Why is your HTML inside `<script>`?

Comment: That is the requirement.I need to get the tag from somewhere else( .js file )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block` to the elements.

```
    <script>
     File :<input type="file" name="files" style="display: inline-block;"/>
         <img src="abc.jpg" style="display: inline-block;"/>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using "inline-block". For Example:

```
.element1 {display:inline-block;margin-right:10px; width:200px;} 
.element2 {display:inline-block; width:200px;} 

<div id="element1">  File :<input type="file" name="files"/> </div> 
<div id="element2">  <img src="abc.jpg"/> </div>
```

inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a width and a height.

Answer (score 1):

```
By default input and img tags are inline elements, It will not go to next line.

Issue here is you have used <script> instead of <div>
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/hhvu1sdk/)